# Cannot configure a TFS build agent with Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, powershell-ise, build-agent

After downloading the vNext build agent from VSTS page or from on-premises TFS, I followed the steps to configure agent in Powershell ISE.

Upon running `.\config.cmd`, there is a display of `>> Connect`:

There is no other prompt further to proceed with the configuration like below.

[image: CannotConfigurevNextAgentwithPowershellISE]

Tried the same with Powershell console and it worked.

Why is it so? Why is it not working with ISE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PowerShell ISE does not support console applications that require interactive input. You can check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/02/04/console-application-non-support-in-the-ise/) blog.

So you need to use PowerShell Console or Command Prompt to config build agent.